# Is there an alternative for haskell underscore in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

Lets imagine that I have haskell-like class Maybe in c++. For example, it can be implemented like that:

```
template<typename T, typename val> 
struct Maybe;

template<typename val> struct Maybe<std::true_type, val> {  
    using value = val; 
};

template<> struct Maybe<std::false_type, void> {

};

template<typename val> 
using Just = Maybe<std::true_type, val>;

using Nothing = Maybe<std::false_type, void>;
```

I want to compare them by using "equal" function:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
struct equal;
```

If I have instance `<Just<T>, Just<R>>`, I need both types `T` and `R` to know the result of the comparison, but in case of `<Just<T>, Nothing>` or `<Nothing, Just<T>>` I don't need to know anything about the type T. In haskell you can use underscore (`Just _`), but is there anything similar in c++?

Comment: FYI, your `Maybe` is `enable_if_t` verbatim.

Comment: *instance <Just<T>, Just<R>>* - that's not a valid instance parameters. If you need to handle a case when one or both of template parameters of `equal` is `Nothing` then you can write a corresponding partial specializations.

Comment: @VTT https://ideone.com/u5cB3e What do you mean by "that's not a valid instance parameters"? I simply want to get rid of `template<typename T>` inside `<Just<T>, Nothing>` and `<Nothing, Just<T>>` instances

Comment: The *don't need to know anything about the type* could probably be handled with specializations of `equal`, but it is really unclear what you want to do. Are you trying to see if two types are the same?

Comment: *I simply want to get rid of template<typename T>* - you can not unfortunately. Template declarations have rather specific syntax

Comment: @jxh I want to write something like `template<> struct equal<Just<_>, Nothing>` without declaring type `T`, because I don't need to know it as I already know the result of comparison

Comment: @НикитаЛарионов - I don't think it's possible, in C++, exactly what do you want. What is more similar (as far I understand) is an unnamed typename (`template <typename> struct foo;`) when you declare a template argument without using it. But this is possible only in the main template declaration, not in specializations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `_` is a valid identifier for a template parameter, but omitting `typename _` will prevent it from being recognized as a template parameter. So the closest you can get would be this:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
struct equal;

template<typename T, typename R>
struct equal<Just<T>, Just<R>> {
    using value = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, R>::value, True, False>::type;
};

template<typename _>
struct equal<Just<_>, Nothing> {
    using value = False;
};

template<typename _>
struct equal<Nothing, Just<_>> {
    using value = False;
};

template<>
struct equal<Nothing, Nothing> {
    using value = True;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But it is a pity that the problem doesn't have an appropriate solution.

Comment: Not sure but... if `True` and `False` are `using`s for, respectively, `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`... instead of `typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, R>::value, True, False>::type;` isn't better (well... at last shorter) `std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, R>::value>;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you want but... I suppose you want something as

```
template <typename, typename>
struct JustEqual : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct JustEqual<Just<T>, Just<T>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

This way, `JustEqual` inherit from `std::true_type` iff (if and only if) both typenames are `Just<T>` types for the same `T`.

When the typename are `Just` types for different types, or a `Just` type and a `Nothing` or two `Nothing`, the `JustEqual` specialization doesn't matches and only the main version (that inherit from `std::false_type`).

Observe that, this way, `JustEqual<Nothing, Nothing>` matches only with the main version so inherit from `std::false_type`. Isn't clear to me if this is what you want.

If you want that `JustEqual<Nothing, Nothing>` inherit from `std::true_type`, you can add a specific specialization

```
template <>
struct JustEqual<Nothing, Nothing> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question about a wildcard type for template parameters.

Looking at your particular problem, You can simplify your definition of `equal` if you define it in terms of `Maybe` instead of `Just` and `Nothing`. What is important is that both parameters of `Maybe` be the same, and so this would be true of `Nothing` as well.

This allows a simplification for the definition of `equal`, since now it can default to `False`.

```
template<typename, typename>
struct equal {
    using value = False;
};

template<typename B, typename V>
struct equal<Maybe<B, V>, Maybe<B, V>> {
    using value = True;
};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZGxbsIwEIbn@ilO6gIiDJ0qJSFDhw6V2gmxoqsxYMkJaXyuhBCv3tR2AiEkVEKNF/usu@//747n@ZQrzDblo8y4MisBMe1zsaQCJemk1FQYTjAvjIhYHbyi0jZiJNJcIQlfkWEqYB7A@f2NKjlVvOP@s7@ikxVrWoWh/bAebFLgM@AAwMAeo2W2cV9GwMzdEbBjxKAhJ9ClrZ3hE24nV5bXLmrZAVapvBlNVuS2K4eoUj92tHX37E/VXslmYuc5iC@DCg49DdeTv2H@5WL6izYtrnzZjEUSwEVgR8Ee2iLVro9RKTOCFGU2GtdmNCFJvkStRUEj36TUS2314krFjSz2vQbNMwlDjw48@RSNozuQ1klNdK9BgXyLxQXRT/heZL3@4YCNxxo9BK/ayzDAVsdXW/4XsGPvasXH8oevFW50ObWUGZ9Mnp5/AQ)